# How to get polygons from part of grid that represents modeling result

Tags: c#, grid, gis, modeling, vectorization

I have grid that represents result of some modelling process. In this case it is forest fire.

[image: Forest fire modelling result]

Sometime fire region may have empty spaces, or it can be split into two or more regions. I need to convert that part(s) of grid that contains fire elements (or element with high temperature) into polygon(s). This polygons will be saved into *.kml file later.
I think that it is basically looks like vectorization task for monochrome image (I need only fire region polygons in result). Or it is different way to realize that?

Someone can recommend simple (it is not rgb image) and precise (mistakes must be minimal) algorithm to convert that part(s) of grid into polygons or possible some opens source realization of that algorithm?

By the way, I use DotSpatial, so maybe that engine have some built-in features to resolve that kind of tasks?

Answer (score 1):

The convex hull algorithm (see for example CLRS: Introduction to Algorithms Chp 33) will create a convex polygon around a given set of points, and it is trivial to implement. You will have to extend it (post process) if you want multiple regions to minimize the low temperature areas within the polygons.

Comment: There is problem. Fire region is not always convex.

Comment: You find the convex hull, H, of all your polygons in one go. Then use the polygon fill algorithm for random points inside H. Each run of polygon fill will give you a new polygon. And you stop when all points inside H has been accounted for. For example, if you pick a point with high temperature the polygon fill algorithm will add all the neighbouring elements which are also high temperature. Then you check if there are any unaccounted points in your original H polygon. If so, you pick one at random and do polygon fill again.